# cannot create larger AVI video using OPENCV

Tags: opencv

I have a series of about 600 JPEG images with sequential filenames. what I need is to create an AVI video. `cvCreateVideoWriter` didn't return NULL! Initially frames got started to form video but after few frames program terminates... i don't know what i am going wrong.

can anyone help? i would really appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, but where's your code? How can we help you without seeing what you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV uses VFW and only creates standard AVI files which are limited to 2Gb

You can use ffmpeg to create either mp4 or extended openDML type AVIs

The easiest solution is normally to pipe image frames to something like memcoder rather than having to deal with the details of the video library yourself - see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs